# Area interaction model sufficient statistics calculation algorithm

Tags: r, algorithms, point-process, c++

I'm currently trying to write a simulation algorithm in Rcpp for a point process model which requires calculating the sufficient statistics for an Area interaction point process model. It entails a Voronoi cell area calculation but with a subtle difference in that it is not exactly a Voronoi tessellation but rather a Voronoi cell of circles with fixed radius. More specifically, Voronoi tessellation can be considered as growing circles around each point but now the circles can only grow to a fixed radius and then stop. I know `ppm` from the `spatstat` package for fitting area interaction model certainly has an implementation for such algorithm but there isn't any source code available. Can anyone send me a source or pointers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: All spatstat code is open source and available both from CRAN and GitHub. You may be looking for a function called something like areaGain... You can call an R function from C++ so that maybe be an easy way to access the sufficient statistic. Good luck!

Comment: Ah! I didn't know such a function existed in `spatstat`. Thanks for pointing that out! Much appreciated!